# How to determine if ftp/smtp is up and running using a script?

Tags: monitoring, smtp, ftp, python, ruby

Similiar to how these uptime monitoring servieces perform checks if your smtp or ftp server is running, how could I do this myself using python/ruby?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is exactly what you want: https://github.com/sebastien/watchdog

I've used it(customized) quite extensively. Enjoy!